# "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-state

I got this error from React - "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop". I found some questions with the same error but I couldn't figure out how to fix mine.

The error said that it occurred due to the `setShow(2)` in the response to the axios post request. The `setPercent` just 2 lines before and the other states seem to work properly though. You can find `setShow` and `setPercent` at the `else` of the long if-else statement.

The Show is set to 0 by default. Once the form data is verified using the if-else statements, it is set to 1 and that displays the loading animation component. And once the backend gives its response Show is set to 2 which removes the loading animation and displays the result component. The loading animation works properly but once the response is received and `setShow` runs, I get the error. The `console.log` right before the `setShow` works properly too.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import Loading from "./Loading.jsx"
import Result from "./Result.jsx"

const Data = () => {
    const [Gender, setGender] = useState('Select')
    const [Age, setAge] = useState(null)
    const [NSS, setNSS] = useState(null)
    const [Parch, setParch] = useState(null)
    const [Fare, setFare] = useState(null)
    const [Clss, setClss] = useState('Select')
    const [Deck, setDeck] = useState('Select')
    const [Town, setTown] = useState('Select')
    const [Alone, setAlone] = useState('Select')
    const [Show, setShow] = useState(0)
    const [Percent, setPercent] = useState(null)
    
    const show = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        if(Gender == "Select"){
            alert("You have to select a gender")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Age != parseInt(Age)){
            alert("Age has to be an integer")
        }
        else if(parseInt(Age) < 0){
            alert("Age has to be more than or equal to 0")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(NSS != parseInt(NSS)){
            alert("Number of Siblings/Spouse has to be an integer")
        }
        else if(parseInt(NSS) < 0){
            alert("Number of Siblings/Spouse has to be more than or equal to 0")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Parch != parseInt(Parch)){
            alert("Parch has to be an integer")
        }
        else if(parseInt(Parch) < 0){
            alert("Parch has to be more than or equal to 0")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Fare != parseFloat(Fare)){
            alert("Fare has to be an number")
        }
        else if(parseInt(Fare) <= 0){
            alert("Fare has to be more than 0")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Clss == "Select"){
            alert("You have to select a Class")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Deck == "Select"){
            alert("You have to select a Deck")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Town == "Select"){
            alert("You have to select a Town")
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        else if(Alone == "Select"){
            alert("You have to select an option in 'Alone'")
        }
        else{
            setShow(1)
            var altgen
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            if(Gender == "Female"){
                altgen = "female"
            }
            else{
                altgen = "male"
            }
            var altalone
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            if(Alone == "Yes"){
                altalone = "y"
            }
            else{
                altalone = "n"
            }
            axios.post('/api', {
                Gender: altgen,
                Age: Age,
                NSS: NSS,
                Parch: Parch,
                Fare: Fare,
                Clss: Clss,
                Deck: Deck,
                Town: Town,
                Alone: altalone
            })
            .then((response) => {
                setPercent(response.data.percentage)
                console.log(response.data.percentage)
                setShow(2)
            })
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
        <div className="mainInp">
            <div className="formGrid">
                <form onSubmit={show}>
                    <div className="inputForm">
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Gender</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <select name="gender" className="dropdown" value={Gender} onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}>
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <input type="text" className="textbox" value={Age} onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)} required />
                        </div>

                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Number of Siblings/Spouse</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <input type="text" className="textbox" value={NSS} onChange={(e) => setNSS(e.target.value)} required />
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Number of Parents/Children</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <input type="text" className="textbox" value={Parch} onChange={(e) => setParch(e.target.value)} required />
                        </div>

                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Fare</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <input type="text" className="textbox" value={Fare} onChange={(e) => setFare(e.target.value)} required />
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Class</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <select name="clss" className="dropdown" value={Clss} onChange={(e) => setClss(e.target.value)}>
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="First">First</option>
                            <option value="Second">Second</option>
                            <option value="Third">Third</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Deck</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <select name="deck" className="dropdown" value={Deck} onChange={(e) => setDeck(e.target.value)}>
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
                            <option value="A">A</option>
                            <option value="B">B</option>
                            <option value="C">C</option>
                            <option value="D">D</option>
                            <option value="E">E</option>
                            <option value="F">F</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Embark Town</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <select name="embtown" className="dropdown" value={Town} onChange={(e) => setTown(e.target.value)}>
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="Southampton">Southampton</option>
                            <option value="Cherbourg">Cherbourg</option>
                            <option value="Queenstown">Queenstown</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>

                        <div className="inputField">
                        <label>Alone</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="inputField">
                        <select name="alone" className="dropdown" value={Alone} onChange={(e) => setAlone(e.target.value)}>
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" className="submitButton" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
            {Show === 1 && (
                <Loading />
            )}
            {Show === 2 && (
                <Result percentage={Percent} />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Data
```

Any help will be appreciated

Edit:

As people commented, the error was in the Result component. I probably should've checked that earlier. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show detail of `Result` component

Comment: I think the problem is inside the Result component. Because you're not getting any error when you're not rendering Result.

Comment: And instead of Show===2 it's better to check if the Percent Value is number and if it was, send it to the <Result/> component

Comment: State updates cause a re-render, if the error doesn't occur until you render `<Result>` this is where the error must be.